# How to show overlay loading screen when switching between two Activities on Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, loading

I have two activities in my Android project:

- LoginActivity
- DashboardActivity

When user starts the app, auto sign-in tasks are done on `LoginActivity` (takes few seconds, fullscreen spinner is shown), then `DashboardActivity` is launched. On the `DashboardActivity` we are again loading some blocking data (again, fullscreen spinner).

I would like to use single fullscreen loading screen for this, that will be shown as soon as `LoginActivity` start loading data and end when `DashboardActivity` stops loading data.

Current status is, that I have duplicated fragment that is used in both Activities. This of course causes the spinner to change (blink/slide animation) when you change activities.

I was thining about having third activity that will get launched as an overlay until both activities finish their work, but I am not sure if that is possible.

Comment: Try looking at [How to add Slide animation between activities in android?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-slide-animation-between-activities-in-android/?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=E95A247356874441B082AE7F7D7BB629)

Comment: @AliasCartellano I was not asking about slide animation.